# Deploying Apache CXF webservice on Jboss5.1.0 throws exception

Tags: cxf

I am trying to deploy web service built using APACHE-CXF on Jboss5.1.0.
It throws the following exception :

```
javax.servlet.servletException : Unrecognized HTTP request or response object.
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstarctHTTPServlet.java:154)
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing any geronimo-servlet.jar in the web application's classpath.